# Hosting two websites from the same webserver

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, hosting, virtualhost, vhosts

On my webserver, I want to serve several websites just based on domain name.

For example, I want a webserver that will serve "mycoolsite.com" and "badstuff.org".

I pointed both sites at the same IP address. In httpd-vhosts, I made two entries:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /www/mycoolsite
  ServerName www.mycoolsite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /www/badstuff
  ServerName www.badstuff.org
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I go to badstuff.org, I get served mycoolsite.com! Why is this happening?

[Apache Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html)

I also know that when I use MAMP, I have to adjust my "hosts" file too. Is this relevant?

Comment: Keep in mind `www.mycoolsite.com` and `mycoolsite.com` are two different names. Does your problem occur only when you call `badstuff.org` or even `www.badstuff.org`? If yes, just adding `ServerAlias badstuff.org` in your 2nd vhost might solve this.

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the `NameVirtualHost` directive **before** the vhosts declaration ?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your configuration by command:

```
$/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S
```

If everything is OK, try to check again by restarting the server.